# ASP Classic >> List all instances of an active session variable

Tags: loops, session, asp-classic, session-variables

Our ASP Classic application assigns a Session("User_ID") for every user that logs in.

I have played around with Session.Contents, but that just returns the sessions associated with my login.

Is there any way to see all of the application's active Session("User_ID") values?

In other words, if the application has assigned Session("User_ID") = "15", Session("User_ID") = "27", Session("User_ID") = "149" and Session("User_ID") = "234", I would like to loop through some collection and get "15, 27, 149, 234".

Is this possible?

Comment: You can only access the session variables from your current session object, not every active session object being stored in IIS. So no, I don't believe it's possible. What you could do in your database backend is keep a `last_logged_in` date/time value, a `last_logged_out` value (when the user clicks "logout") , and even a `last_seen` value, which would be a global IF statement along the lines of `If NOT IsEmpty(Session("User_ID")) Then <code to update the "last_seen" column in the user table for User_ID = Session("User_ID")> End If`. That way you can use your database to see who is online.

Comment: You can do this using an [`Application` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525360(v=vs.90)) variable. Every time a new [session start  event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524776(v=vs.90)) is fired you update a `Dictionary` that is stored in an `Application` object variable. These variables persist for the duration of the application and are only cleared if the web application is stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Usually what you do is to update a database table which has that userID and update a lastActivity datetime column.  Simplest would be to have every page call a common include that updates this.  Another option is if you have a timer that logs them out automatically is to update a flag to say they aren't logged in anymore.